# Why does in_array returns false with Object::Class as key?

Tags: php, php-7.3

This is weird and I can't understand why.

I have this array:

```
$exludedAction = [UserController::class => [
            "login", "register"
    ]
];
```

When I check if the key is in_array it returns false:

```
$type = get_class($userControllerObject);
$cl = in_array($type, $exludedAction); // is false
```

I check for strict comparison:
`$c = $type === UserController::class; // returns true`

Note that `UserController::class` is inside a namespace: `App\namespace\class`.

And also check with `isset` returns true:
`isset($exludedAction[$type]); // returns true`

Comment: `in_array` searches for *values*, not *keys*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) searches an array for *values*, not *keys*. You should use [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead:

```
$exludedAction = [UserController::class => [
            "login", "register"
    ]
];


$type = get_class($userControllerObject);
$cl = array_key_exists($type, $exludedAction);

var_dump($cl);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Ed9ls)